# What is the meaning of Flint Lockwood words to Tim?

Tags: plot-explanation, cloudy-with-a-chance-of-meatballs-2

In **[Cloudy with a Chance of Meatballs 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1985966/)**, Flint Lockwood say this words to Tim.

> Flint:And they're being held in the factory?
>
> Tim: We gotta get them out of there.
>
> Flint: **But how? There's just two of us**.

He says "**There's just two of us**", which totally unclear What he is trying to say to his father ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By saying "There's just two of us", he meant that there are only two human beings(less in number). How could we rescue from the factory. He didn't had idea that foodimals would help him to save his friends. What he meant?

> Flint: **But how? There's just two of us**. (How will be able to rescue them? We are less in number.)

Then berry gives a war cry and the foodimals help flint and his father to save his friends.